# Need help how Bloc stream and sink work. Can't figure out how my fetchContactList function inside ContactBloc called in each screen when i navigate

Tags: flutter, bloc, rxdart

I am new to flutter development and exploring it. I have created one sample contact app using Flutter modular (Bloc with rxDart).

Screens are

1) ContactPage        -- to show contact list

2) AddContactPage     -- to add contact

3) ViewContactPage    -- to view contact

4) EditContactPage    -- to edit contact

I have common ContactBloc class which has following function

fetchContactList

fetchContactListBySearch

insertContact

updateContact

deleteContact

One thing I am unable to understand is why the fetchContactList  function is called each time when I navigate to other than the ContactPage screen. Since I am calling the fetchContactList function inside the build method of ContactPage and after the edit delete operation.
I am unable to figure out these things.

Below are the ContactBloc file

```
class ContactBloc extends Disposable {
  final ContactRepository contactRepository=
      ContactModule.to.get<ContactRepository>();

  List<Contact> contacts;
  Contact contact;
  bool searchButton= false;
  bool showSearch= false;

  BehaviorSubject<List<Contact>> _listContactController;
  BehaviorSubject<Contact> _contactController;
  BehaviorSubject<bool> _searchButtonController;
  BehaviorSubject<bool> _searchController;

  ContactBloc() {
    Story.storyline(story: "ContactBloc()");
    _listContactController= BehaviorSubject.seeded(contacts);
    _contactController= BehaviorSubject.seeded(contact);
    _searchButtonController= BehaviorSubject.seeded(searchButton);
    _searchController= BehaviorSubject.seeded(showSearch);
  }

  Stream<List<Contact>> get listContactOut => _listContactController.stream;
  Stream<Contact> get contactOut => _contactController.stream;
  Stream<bool> get searchOut => _searchController.stream;
  Stream<bool> get buttonSearchOut => _searchButtonController.stream;

  Future<Answer> fetchContactList({
      bool distinct, List<String> columns,
      String where, List whereArgs,
      String groupBy, String having,
      String orderBy,
      int limit, int offset
    }) async {
    //Story.storyline(story: "ContactBloc.fetchContactList[+]");
    Answer A= await contactRepository.fetch(
        distinct: distinct, columns: columns, where: where,
        whereArgs: whereArgs, groupBy: groupBy, having: having,
        orderBy: orderBy, limit: limit, offset: offset
    );
    _listContactController.sink.add(A.data);
    return A;
  }

  Future<Answer> fetchContactListBySearch(String keywords) async {
    keywords= "%$keywords%";
    Answer A= await fetchContactList(
      where: "name LIKE ? OR phone LIKE ? OR email LIKE ?",
      whereArgs: [keywords, keywords, keywords]
    );
    return A;
  }

  Future<Answer> insertContact(Contact contact) async {
    Answer A= await contactRepository.insert(contact);
    fetchContactList();
    return A;
  }

  Future<Answer> updateContact(Contact contact) async {
    Answer A= await contactRepository.update(contact);
    fetchContactList();
    return A;
  }

  Future<Answer> deleteContact(Contact contact) async {
    Answer A= await contactRepository.delete(contact);
    fetchContactList();
    return A;
  }
...
}
```

you can find sample project for your reference here

https://github.com/dineshrajbhar777/flutter-bloc-with-rxdart.git